# XML file reading into array, printing it out - While loop not working

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, while-loop

I am trying to read an XML file into an array and then print it out, however, for some reason it only works if my `while` has only one argument.

The conditions that I am trying to use: `while (xtr.Name != "Vakarinis" || xtr.Name != "Dieninis")` It keeps looping forever. However, if I only specify `while (xtr.Name != "Vakarinis")` it works perfectly, and reads the `<Vakarinis>` elements. I tried using |, ||, brackets, but nothing worked. What couldbe the problem?

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;


namespace xml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Studentai s = new Studentai();  

            XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader("Uzduotis.xml");
            xtr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
            xtr.Read();

            while (!xtr.EOF) 
            {
                if (xtr.Name == "studentai" && !xtr.IsStartElement()) break;


                // NOT WORKING --------------------------------------------
                while (xtr.Name != "Vakarinis" || xtr.Name != "Dieninis")
                // NOT WORKING --------------------------------------------


                {

                        Console.WriteLine(xtr.Name);
                        xtr.Read(); 

                } 


                Studentas tc = new Studentas(); 
                tc.laikas = xtr.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(tc.laikas);
                tc.id = xtr.GetAttribute("id");          
                Console.WriteLine(tc.id);
                tc.vardas = xtr.GetAttribute("vardas");
                Console.WriteLine(tc.vardas);
                xtr.Read();                              
                xtr.Read();

                tc.modulis1 = xtr.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(tc.modulis1);
                xtr.Read();
                tc.paz1 = xtr.ReadElementString("paz1"); 
                Console.WriteLine(tc.paz1);
                tc.paz2 = xtr.ReadElementString("paz2"); 
                Console.WriteLine(tc.paz2);
                xtr.Read();                             

                tc.modulis2 = xtr.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(tc.modulis2);
                xtr.Read();
                tc.paz3 = xtr.ReadElementString("paz1");
                Console.WriteLine(tc.paz3);
                tc.paz4 = xtr.ReadElementString("paz2"); 
                Console.WriteLine(tc.paz4);
                xtr.Read();
                xtr.Read();
                tc.vidurkis = xtr.ReadElementString("vidurkis"); 
                Console.WriteLine(tc.vidurkis);
                s.items.Add(tc); 
                xtr.Read(); 
                Console.Read();
            } 

            xtr.Close(); 
            s.Display(); 


        }
    }

    public class Studentas
    {
        public string laikas;
        public string id;
        public string vardas;
        public string modulis1;
        public string paz1;
        public string paz2;
        public string modulis2;
        public string paz3;
        public string paz4;
        public string vidurkis;
    }

    public class Studentai
    {
        public ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        public void Display()
        {
            foreach (Studentas tc in items)
            {
                Console.Write(tc.laikas + " " + tc.id + " " + tc.vardas + " " + tc.modulis1 + " " + tc.paz1 + " " + tc.paz2);
                Console.WriteLine(tc.modulis2 + " " + tc.paz3 + " " + tc.paz4 + " " + tc.vidurkis);

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file:

```
  <Vakarinis id="36453" vardas="Petras">
    <pazymiai>
      <matematika>
        <paz1>5</paz1>
        <paz2>7</paz2>
      </matematika>
      <technologija>
        <paz1>8</paz1>
        <paz2>4</paz2>
      </technologija>
    </pazymiai>
    <vidurkis>6.00</vidurkis>
  </Vakarinis>

  <Dieninis id="75643" vardas="Jonas">
    <pazymiai>
      <matematika>
        <paz1>8</paz1>
        <paz2>7</paz2>
      </matematika>
      <fizika>
        <paz1>7</paz1>
        <paz2>10</paz2>
      </fizika>
    </pazymiai>
    <vidurkis>8</vidurkis>
  </Dieninis>

  <Dieninis id="48843" vardas="Andrius">
    <pazymiai>
      <matematika>
        <paz1>5</paz1>
        <paz2>5</paz2>
      </matematika>
      <fizika>
        <paz1>5</paz1>
        <paz2>7</paz2>
      </fizika>
    </pazymiai>
    <vidurkis>5.50</vidurkis>
  </Dieninis>

  <Vakarinis id="56442" vardas="Antanas">
    <pazymiai>
      <matematika>
        <paz1>8</paz1>
        <paz2>8</paz2>
      </matematika>
      <technologija>
        <paz1>8</paz1>
        <paz2>10</paz2>
      </technologija>
    </pazymiai>
    <vidurkis>8.50</vidurkis>
  </Vakarinis>

</studentai>
```

Comment: I've never seen XmlTextReader used in that way. (Although it may be perfectly OK, I've just never seen that.) The usual way to handle an XML file is to read it into an XmlDocument object, and then use XPath on it.

Comment: Well, that is beyond me :D Should ask our 'professional' lecturers why they made us do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to change

```
while (xtr.Name != "Vakarinis" || xtr.Name != "Dieninis")
```

to:

```
while ((xtr.Name != "Vakarinis") && (xtr.Name != "Dieninis"))
```

Comment: Oh wow, I don't even know what I was thinking -.-' Total logic-fail, thank You for helping me.